# how to load images from different folders and subfolders in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am developing a CNN in a animal classification dataset, which are separated into 2 folders, and the 2 folders involve another subfolders...there are four layers of this structure, and now I want to load them and convert them to n-dimension-arrays to feed to tensorflow, the names of these folders are the labels.
I hope that someone can help me with some concrete codes or some useful materials.
Thank you very much in advance!

Here I will give some examples:
Anisopleura Libellulidae Leach, 1815    Trithemis   aurora
Zygoptera   Calopterygidae Selys, 1850  Calopteryx  splendens
the aurora and splendens are the labels of this problem, and they are also the name of fifth floor subfolders, the images are stored in these folders.
C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\dragonfly\Anisopleura\Libellulidae Leach, 1815\Pseudothemis\zonata

## this is a path.

Comment: An example of the folder layout would be very helpful

Comment: please show your directory structure first.

Comment: C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\dragonfly\Anisopleura\Aeshnidae Leach, 1815\Anax\parthenope               ##this is an example, I guess maybe I get my answer from the following anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[os.walk()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) is what you are looking for.

```
import os

# traverse root directory, and list directories as dirs and files as files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    print((len(path) - 1) * '---', os.path.basename(root))
    for file in files:
        print(len(path) * '---', file)
```

This code will allow you to parse recursively all folders and subfolders. You get the name of the subfolder(labels in your case) and all files in the `file` variable.

The next work for you is then to maybe create a dictionnary (or numpy multi-dimensional array) to store for each label (or subfolder) the features of your image.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I understand this function but I think it can only solve two-layer-subfolders problem, and in my case there are four or more layers, for example, C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\dragonfly\Anisopleura\Aeshnidae Leach, 1815\Anax\parthenope, which is a kind of the data set, and what can I do for this problem?

Comment: Could you detail from those (this ? I don't really see how are cut your paths) paths the label(s) who need to be extract ?

Comment: C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\dragonfly\Anisopleura\Aeshnidae Leach, 1815\Anax\parthenope ## in this example, the "parthenope" is the label, from the concept of zoology, the name of these folders denotes
Suborder, family, genus, species of dragonfly.
I do not know if I am clear, I hope you can understand what I said.

Comment: Only the last folder contains the label ? Is all others folder name should be used ? (dragonfly ? Anisopleura). Could you edit your question with a complete example of what you want to do with a given input ( list of paths to image file for example) and what the script should create as an array ?

Comment: Given what you just add to your question, you should execute the code I had provided with the path : `C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\dragonfly`. You will see that before giving the name of PNG files, there will be the list of the labels you want.

Answer (score 2):

I using openface library for face recognition, In this library iterImgs is method that gives list of you all images under a Directory

For detail [iterImgs](http://openface-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/openface.html#openface.data.iterImgs)

```
from openface.data import iterImgs

imgs = list(iterImgs("Directory path"))

print imgs    # print all images in Directory path also in Tree
```

or another way is defined a vailed extension

```
vailed_ext = [".jpg",".png"]
import os 
f_list = []
def Test2(rootDir):     
    for lists in os.listdir(rootDir): 
        path = os.path.join(rootDir, lists) 
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(path) 
        if file_extension in vailed_ext:
            print path          
            f_list.append[path]
        if os.path.isdir(path): 
           Test2(path)

Test2("/home/")
print f_list
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to load many images from multi subfolders(different paths), what should I do?